# Add custom module in Flex Relate field (vTiger)

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I am trying to add my custom module "My Calls" in Flex relate field. Now there are by default Campaign, Accounts, Leads modules are there.

I am trying to add module using tpl files but I dont think so it will work.

If anyone has some idea on this then please give me some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please use below sql query for that.
INSERT INTO `vtiger_fieldmodulerel` (`fieldid`, `module`, `relmodule`, `status`, `sequence`) VALUES ('237', 'Products', 'Calendar', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO `vtiger_ws_referencetype` (`fieldtypeid`, `type`) VALUES ('34', 'Products');

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you